# Music in a Demo Reel

Tags: music, demo-reel, demo, composition

It looks like Demo Reels are the big question right now, so I'll throw another one out there...

**How do you feel about music in a demo reel?**

I'm a composer/sound designer, and I plan to have a music-less version of my reel, as well as music-only samples, but my main reel will feature both my music and my sound design. Do you feel I'm shooting myself in the foot by doing both, or is my assumption of "I only have 30 seconds to show everything I can do" fairly accurate?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting.. I'm busy wih the same thing;
haven;t figures it out yet, i guess your best off with presenting what you are the most happy with, or you find the strongest illustration of your work, that way you will also atract the right jobs appealing to you..

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do both unless the position you're applying for has use of, or has requested both skill sets. I'd definitely mention it on a resume that you're capable of composing and doing sound design, but for the demo reel, I'd keep it down to what the company or person hiring you is looking for.

Comment: For jobs I'm bidding for, I fully agree.  This is more for just a general demo that I have posted on my site as the first thing people see.